# How to check if the app had opened by clicking a universal link or not in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, appdelegate

currently I'm working on a swift project. Here I implemented deep linking using universal link for verify my email address. And it's working fine. What I need is how to check whether if the app is opened by clicking the universal link or not. Because in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, I'm checking like whether the user is already logged in or not. And if the user is logged in I'm navigating to the home screen else navigating to the login screen. And the checking is happening in the

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

method. And when I click the universal link I also get the callback in

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```

method. And in this method i'm navigating to email verification screen

But the problem is when I click the universal link, it open my app and its navigating to the login screen(because the user is not logged in) and then immediately navigating the email verification screen. Actually, what I need is I don't what to navigate to the login screen or home screen if I came to the app by clicking the universal link. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When opens with deep linking below method triggers in AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
      //Enter Logic Here based on your URL
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try checking the launchOptions available in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate for the key

> **UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey** 
>   A key indicating that the app was
>   launched so that it could open the specified URL.